# Integral of a positive function with arbitrary endpoints

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\Bbb R_+\rightarrow \Bbb R_+$ be integrable and strictly positive. It is well known that $\int_a^{a+1}f(x)dx>0$ for any $a\geq 0$. For fixed $b<\infty$, is it also true that

$$\inf_{0\leq a\leq b}\int_a^{a+1}f(x)dx>0\,? $$

I think the answer should be yes, as there are only a finite number of non-overlapping intervals $[a,a+1]$ for $0\leq a\leq b$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with proving it.

Comment: Nowhere does it say that $a$ is an integer, or that the integrals are only taken over non-overlapping intervals.

Comment: $a$ doesn't have to be an integer (otherwise the result is obvious since there are only finitely many). Since there are infinitely many such $[a,a+1]$, some will overlap.

Comment: And thus your point about there being only a finite number of non-overlapping intervals is entirely irrelevant. When you cannot figure out how to prove something, you should try to disprove it instead. Either you will be successful, and thus will stop wasting your time, or you will be unsucessful, but with additional knowledge about why you couldn't prove it that may guide you towards a proof again.